# Chrome Remote Desktop

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome

I'm trying to set up Chrome Remote Desktop on Ubuntu 21.04. It downloads a .deb file which I then try to install via Terminal.

It starts installing but finally I get this error:

```
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
```

I get this error quite a lot when trying to install apps but I don't know how to fix the problem. Does anyone have suggestions to fix broken packages?

I ran `sudo apt update` and got this result:

```
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable InRelease    
Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease            
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease             
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable Release      
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu hirsute InRelease      
Ign:10 https://www.mediahuman.com/packages/ubuntu hirsute InRelease            
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu hirsute Release       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:12 https://www.mediahuman.com/packages/ubuntu hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 169.60.33.180 443]
Get:13 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:14 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:15 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [9,268 B]
Reading package lists... Done                
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://www.mediahuman.com/packages/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Then I ran `sudo apt upgrade` and got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  google-chrome-stable
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 80.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 19.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 google-chrome-stable amd64 92.0.4515.159-1 [80.2 MB]
Fetched 80.2 MB in 35s (2,318 kB/s)                                            
(Reading database ... 239339 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../google-chrome-stable_92.0.4515.159-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (92.0.4515.159-1) over (85.0.4183.121-1) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (92.0.4515.159-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.68ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu1) ...
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
```

Notice the last line which is what I often get when trying to load software.

I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg` anyway and got this:

```
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: Unpacking and configuring...
libdvd-pkg: Building the package... (it may take a while)
libdvd-pkg: Build log will be saved to /usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss2_1.4.2-1~local_amd64.build
Current: =ep
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read,cap_perfmon,cap_bpf,cap_checkpoint_restore
Ambient set =
Current IAB: !cap_dac_read_search,!cap_fsetid,!cap_kill,!cap_setgid,!cap_setuid,!cap_setpcap,!cap_linux_immutable,!cap_net_bind_service,!cap_net_broadcast,!cap_net_admin,!cap_net_raw,!cap_ipc_lock,!cap_ipc_owner,!cap_sys_module,!cap_sys_rawio,!cap_sys_chroot,!cap_sys_ptrace,!cap_sys_pacct,!cap_sys_admin,!cap_sys_boot,!cap_sys_nice,!cap_sys_resource,!cap_sys_time,!cap_sys_tty_config,!cap_mknod,!cap_lease,!cap_audit_write,!cap_audit_control,!cap_setfcap,!cap_mac_override,!cap_mac_admin,!cap_syslog
Securebits: 024/0x14/5'b10100
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: yes (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: yes (unlocked)
 secure-no-ambient-raise: no (unlocked)
uid=0(root) euid=0(root)
gid=0(root)
groups=0(root)
Guessed mode: UNCERTAIN (0)
libdvd-pkg: Installing...
Selecting previously unselected package libdvdcss-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 239337 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libdvdcss-dev_1.4.2-1~local_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdvdcss-dev:amd64 (1.4.2-1~local) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdvdcss2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libdvdcss2_1.4.2-1~local_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdvdcss2:amd64 (1.4.2-1~local) ...
Setting up libdvdcss2:amd64 (1.4.2-1~local) ...
Setting up libdvdcss-dev:amd64 (1.4.2-1~local) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.33-0ubuntu5) ...
```

Although I've been using Ubuntu for some time, the above details mean little to me as I'm far from an expert. Is there something else I can do now?

Comment: Is your software up-to-date or do you have preexisting problems with your package management? Your software should be maintained and you should pull the list of available software before making any changes to software or adding new software.   Please edit your question with the outputs of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: When you paste text from the terminal please format that text as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Answer (score 0):

Several sources suggest using

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

in this case.
You may try this and post feedback.